# windows batch sqlite backup firefox history

Tags: windows, firefox, batch-file, sqlite, backup

Not familiar with windows stuffs.. , I'm trying to write a little MS Windows batch in order to backup firefox history but I'm not getting the expected result, eg the firefox history dump into a file (not implemented here), and can't figure out why and how to solve. Instead I get a dump of the database in a new window. Here is what I've done till now :

cmd windows terminal

```
start "TEST" sqlite.cmd
```

sqlite.cmd

```
REM backup firefox history
setlocal
set DB_src=places.sqlite
set DB_dest=places1.sqlite
set FF_profile=C:\Documents and Settings\User_A\Application Data\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\1e6xxxxx.default
set SQLITE_EXE=C:\Documents and Settings\Admin_User\SoftWare\sqlite3.exe
set SQLITE_SQL=C:\Documents and Settings\Admin_User\Bureau\sqlite.sql
copy "%FF_profile%\%DB_src%" "%FF_profile%\%DB_dest%"
@echo off
start "%SQLITE_EXE%" "%FF_profile%\%DB_dest%" < "%SQLITE_SQL%"
endlocal
```

sqlite.sql

```
.dump html
.output moz_places.html
SELECT moz_places.visit_count, moz_places.url FROM moz_places ORDER by visit_count DESC LIMIT 20;
```

[EDIT]:
Worked around :
- using the right sqlite query (updated in sqlite.sql below)as for [these examples](http://www.alekz.net/archives/740).
- using the sql html output "moz_places.html" as I could not get the redirection work.
linux stuffs are easier for me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is lame, because it involves three completely unrelated domains: firefox, sqlite, and batch files. You should have isolated the problem by determining whether this is a firefox issue or an sqlite issue or a batch file issue and then you should have come up with a question regarding the domain in which the issue lies, with absolutely no mention to the other domains.

I am going to give you an answer as best as I can regarding batch files:

First of all, you need to stop needlessly using the `start` command and just invoke things directly. So, instead of:

```
start "%SQLITE_EXE%" "%FF_profile%\%DB_dest%" < "%SQLITE_SQL%"
```

You need this:

```
"%SQLITE_EXE%" "%FF_profile%\%DB_dest%" < "%SQLITE_SQL%"
```

Then, you need to redirect the output of the above command into a file of your choice. For this, you need to make use of the '>' operator.  So:

```
"%SQLITE_EXE%" "%FF_profile%\%DB_dest%" < "%SQLITE_SQL%" > myfile.txt
```

That should do it, as far as batch files are concerned. If it does not do it, then it is a firefox or sqlite issue.

Comment: Thx. Tried the redirection but drives to ntg, so I guess, as you said, the issue is else.